# C# ASP.NET MVC @Url.Action does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I know there can be some peculiarities in Visual Studio where it highlights `@URL` as not existing in the current context, but it still works.  The problem I have however I think is different.

I am writing an application at the moment, I have completed numerous admin screens all within there own area.  The main area until now only had a `ViewStart` pointing to a `_Layout` which detected if you were logged in or not displayed a login page (which works) if you aren't and a series of hyper links if you are that take you to the admin pages - which all work.

In the `_Layout` the `@Url` is highlighted as does not exist in the current context - but works fine.

Now I have started writing the main area, so have added an `Index.cshtml`, this has a `@model` which is highlighted as does not exist in the current context, but I am able to access the data within without issue.

The problem is any anchor I add in the page and set the URL using `@Url.Action` doesn't work, they all say does not exist in the current context and when you view the source of the page the `href=` is missing as it the URL.

If I manually code the `href=` it does appear in the source and does work.

**Update:**

So further to comment 2 below, I now have...

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <a href="@Url.Action("new")" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        Create Company
    </a>
</div>

@Html.ActionLink("Create Company","New","Summary")
```

In my `chtml` page and...

```
<a href="@Url.Action("index", "Users", new {area = "Admin"})">User Admin</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("index", "Companies", new {area = "Admin"})">Customer Admin</a>
```

In my _Layout in which the cshtml is rendered, but the resulting html is...

```
<a href="/admin/Users">User Admin</a>
<a href="/admin/Companies">Customer Admin</a>
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>

<h2>
    Overview Screen
</h2>

<br/>

<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        Create Company
    </a>
</div>

<a href="">Create</a>
```

So as you can see, the anchor and @Url.Action works fine in the _Layout, but neither the `@Url.Action` nor `@Html.ActionLink` generates a URL.

Comment: I've resolved all the "does not exist in the current context" issues, the version numbers in 1 of the web.config files was incorrect.  Just need to figure out why my @Url.Actions don't render to a href= on this page.

Comment: Tried changing the anchor and Url.Action Html.ActionLink, very similar result, the only difference is that whereas anchor and Url.Action results in an anchor with no href at all, Html.ActionLink gives an anchor with an empty href.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around the @Url.Action code.

```
<a href='@Url.Action("new")' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">


<a href='@Url.Action("index", "Users", new {area = "Admin"})'>User Admin</a>
<a href='@Url.Action("index", "Companies", new {area = "Admin"})'>Customer Admin</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too.

I think this is related to Attribute Routing and routing precedence. This may happen if you have `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` after a default `routes.MapRoute` definition in your `RouteConfig.cs` file.

You may want to move `routes.MapMvvAttributeRoutes()` before other `routes.MapRoute` definition.

Answer (score 0):

You should check routing. If ok then check plesk version, because if it is old or not updated then your pages will not working and this error will always appear.

[image]